# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token in my 'DataRequests' dto

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, rest-assured

I've got a highly nested api responce:

```
{
"dataRequests": [
    {
        "status": "success",
        "title": "token",
        "values": {
            "limit": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "count": 1,
            "total": 1,
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "DOMAIN",
                    "permission": "default",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "property:id",
                            "value": 390
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "setting:crawler:token",
                            "value": "here's a token"
                        }
                    ],
                    "filters": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
 }
```

I tried to parse it by using many wrappers. Because from just one dataRequest dto it returns 'null' when i want to get field 'value' with token.

But faced a problem while compile:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize 
  instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
  at [Source: {"dataRequests":[{"status":"success","title":"token","values": 
   {"limit":1,"offset":0,"count":1,"total":1,"elements": 
  [{"type":"DOMAIN","permission":"default","properties":[{"name":"property:id","value":390}, 
  {"name":"setting:crawler:token","value":"here's a token"}],"filters":[]}]}}]}; line: 1, column: 
      17] (through reference chain: com.rest.dto.ProjectTokenDto["dataRequests"])
```

My DTO's:

ProjectTokenDto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProjectTokenDto {

    private Map<String, ValuesDto> dataRequests;

}
```

Values dto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ValuesDto {

    private Map<String, List<ElementsDto>> values;
}
```

Elements dto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ElementsDto {

    private Map<String, List<PropertiesDto>> elements;
}
```

Properties dto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PropertiesDto {

    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

Then I tried to parse this tree with not the best way, but i can't understand how to parse it more easily? And getting Exception above:

```
ProjectTokenDto wrapper = graphQLSteps.postProjectToken(id);

        Map<String, ValuesDto> values = wrapper.getDataRequests();

        Map<String, List<ElementsDto>> elements = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, List<PropertiesDto>> properties = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ValuesDto> entry : values.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("values")) {
                elements.put(entry.getKey(), (List<ElementsDto>) entry.getValue().getValues());
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<ElementsDto>> entry : elements.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("elements")) {
                properties.put(entry.getKey(), (List<PropertiesDto>) entry.getValue().get(0).getElements());
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<PropertiesDto>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().get(0).getValue().equals(Long.toString(id))) {
                token = entry.getValue().get(0).getValue();
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Change  private Map<String, ValuesDto> dataRequests to private List< ValuesDto> dataRequests;

And have another Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
 at [Source: {"dataRequests":[{"status":"success","title":"token","values":{"limit":1,"offset":0,"count":1,"total":1,"elements":[{"type":"DOMAIN","permission":"default","properties":[{"name":"property:id","value":390},{"name":"setting:crawler:token","value":"here's a token"}],"filters":[]}]}}]}; line: 1, column: 72] (through reference chain: com.rest.dto.ProjectTokenDto["dataRequests"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.rest.dto.ValuesDto["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["limit"])
```

Tried to ignore it manualy by changing JsonIgnoreProperties to

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"limit", "offset", "count", "total", "status", "title"})
```

in the valuesDto, but eventually have the same Exception

Comment: `dataRequests` is a list, not a map

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you, but after changing from     private Map<String, ValuesDto> dataRequests; to private List<ValuesDto> dataRequests; I have a new problem. Write it in 'Update'

Comment: You have no limit field, so I'm not sure. But your values dto needs a list field named elements

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing dto's values:

ProjectTokenDto:

```
private List<DataRequestDto> dataRequests;
```

DataRequestsDto:

```
private ValuesDto values;
```

ValuesDto:

```
private List<ElementsDto> elements;
```

ElementsDto:

```
private List<PropertiesDto> properties;
```

And finally, propertiesDto:

```
private String name;
private String value;
```